# How do I check if an externalptr is NULL from within R

Tags: r, swig

I'm using SWIG to generate wrapper code to access C code from within the R language.  The wrapper code uses the R `externalptr` type to hold references to C pointers.  In some situations, those pointers are NULL on the C side, which show up in R as a nil value when displayed.  On the R side, calling `is.null()` and `is.na()` on the `externalptr` both return `FALSE`.  For example:

```
> val = librdf_query_results_get_binding_value(results, 2)
> val
An object of class "_p_librdf_node_s"
Slot "ref":
<pointer: (nil)>
> class(val@ref)
[1] "externalptr"
> is.null(val@ref)
[1] FALSE
> is.na(val@ref)
[1] FALSE
```

As can be seen from the code output above, the `ref` slot contains an `externalptr`, which is "nil".  How do I determine from within R that this pointer in C is NULL?

If you want to see the code in context, it is available in GitHub:
  https://github.com/ropensci/redland-bindings/blob/master/R/redland/inst/tests/test.redland_base.R#L40

Comment: I think you may need a C/C++ helper function that evaluates the external pointer for you.

Comment: I think @DirkEddelbuettel is right. You might want to consider `bigmemory::is.nil` as a guide.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel, I suspected as much. So do you think that overriding is.null() for the `externalptr` type would be reasonable, or would it be better to put it in my own package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness, here's the solution I used.  It required a function on the C side, and one on the R side, as suggested by @DirkEddelbuettel. The C function is:

```
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP isnull(SEXP pointer) {
  return ScalarLogical(!R_ExternalPtrAddr(pointer));
}
```

And the wrapper function in R is:

```
is.null.externalptr <- function(pointer) {
  stopifnot(is(pointer, "externalptr"))
  .Call("isnull", pointer)
}
```

For an example of use from within R:

```
> p <- new("externalptr")
> p
<pointer: (nil)>
> is.null.externalptr(p)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 6):

The `C` solution above is most elegant, but a compiler might not always be available. A solution that does not require compiled code could be something like:

```
identical(pointer, new("externalptr"))
```

However this would not work if the object has custom attributes. If this is the case, you could do:

```
isnull <- function(pointer){
  a <- attributes(pointer)
  attributes(pointer) <- NULL
  out <- identical(pointer, new("externalptr"))
  attributes(pointer) <- a
  return(out)
}
```

Again a bit more involved than the C solution, but will work in a simple script on any platform.